# IBM Connections Activities

Tags: vba, ibm-connections

I need to Export IBM Connections Activity to csv file by VBA. Do you have any experience with this? It can be done manually by clicking on Edit Activity -> Export Activity -> Export

Edited: 
Yes, I am using IBM Connections, interacting on web page in a browser. When I used inspect element, I saw that code for export button is this

```
<input class="lotusBtn" dojoattachpoint="exportAct_AP" value="Export" dojoattachevent="onclick:exporter" type="button">
```

so I tried something like this, but I am not still able to fully identify click action:

```
Sub IEACObject2()
Dim i As Long
Dim objCollection As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://w3-connections.ibm.com/activities/service/html/mainpage#activitypage,25e2e3b1-c4e9-4448-95ae-b72432871095"
Do While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop
Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
  If (objCollection(i).Type = "button" And objCollection(i).Value = "Export") Then
       objCollection(i).Click
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Perhaps you could record a macro of you doing this manually?

Comment: If I right understand you are using _IBM Connections_ via web interface, i. e. interacting on a web page in a browser? Could you please share a link to a screenshot of the webpage, and the webpage HTML content? If you use standalone application then it's better to switch to e. g. AutoIt, which is more flexible for automation.

Answer (score 1):

there are API's available. 
On Premises : https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+5.5+API+Documentation
Cloud: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf
You should be able to find all the infos there.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the atom feed (XML) : https://YOUR-CONNECTIONS-SERVER/activities/service/atom2/descendants?nodeUuid=YOUR-ACTIVITY-UID

There is a button for this feed in every activity

I am sure VBA is able to deal with (atom) XML